# Is it possible to add two float inside the for loop?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm creating a simple grade calculator with C++, I'm just new in C++, and I am practicing it, but I am having a problem with my method or with my code, hope you'll help me out with this one. I don't have an idea if it is possible to add up the user input (using float numbers) inside the for loop method and print it out. Thank you and happy new year!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    float sum = 0.00, avg, grades [10], i;

    cout << "\n Enter your grades on each subject\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------";
    cout << "\n Chemistry for Engineers Laboratory: ";
    cin >> grades [0];
    cout << "\n Chemistry for Engineers: ";
    cin >> grades [1];
    cout << "\n Computer Aided Drafting: ";
    cin >> grades [2];
    cout << "\n Calculus";
    cin >> grades [3];
    cout << "\n Kontekstwalisadong Komunikasyon sa Filipino at sa Iba't-ibang Larangan: ";
    cin >> grades [4];
    cout << "\n Science Technology and Society: ";
    cin >> grades [5];
    cout << "\n Mathematics in the Modern World: ";
    cin >> grades [6];
    cout << "\n Movemement Enhancement (Physical Education): ";
    cin >> grades [7];
    cout << "\n Readings in Philippine History: ";
    cin >> grades [8];
    cout << "\n Undertanding the Self: ";
    cin >> grades [9];

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf ("%.1f + %.1f\n", sum , avg, sum+avg);
    }
    cout << "----------------------------------------";
    cout << "Total Grade: " << sum;
    avg = sum / 10;
    cout << "\n GWA: " << avg;
    cout << "\n Rating: ";

    if ( avg > 1.00) {
        cout << "Excellent";
    } else if ( avg > 3.00 && avg <= 2.00) {
        cout << "Passed";
    } else if ( avg > 4.00 && avg <= 3.00) {
        cout << "Conditional Passing";
    } else {
        cout << "Failed";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf ("%.1f + %.1f\n", sum , avg, sum+avg);` Why there's a `sum+avg`?

Comment: Ohh. sorry sir, that's the part were I am having a problem with, I don't have an any idea on how to add those two float. Hehe. Sorry sorry sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `printf` is meant to writes the results to `stdout`.
2. condition check for grade evaluation is not correct average grade more than 1.0 is considered as Excellent

Below snippet shows right usage of `for-loop`

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <array>
    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<float> grades;
        const std::vector<std::string>  subjects = {
            "Chemistry for Engineers Laboratory",
            "Chemistry for Engineers", 
            "Computer Aided Drafting",
            "Calculus",
            "Kontekstwalisadong Komunikasyon sa Filipino at sa Iba't-ibang Larangan"
            //Extend the subjects
        };

        int TotlaSubject = subjects.size();

        std::cout << "\n Enter your grades on each subject\n";
        std::cout << "-----------------------------------------------\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < TotlaSubject; i++)
        {
            std::cout << subjects[i] << " : ";
            float InputGrade;
            std::cin >> InputGrade;
            grades.push_back(InputGrade);
//          ^^^^^ here pushing data into the in a loop
        }

        float total =0.0;
        for (auto grade : grades){
            total += grade;  //Adding grades in a loop
         }

        float avg = total / grades.size();
        std::cout << "Total : " << total << " Avg : " << avg << std::endl;        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Gotcha sir! ...and for the grade evaluation, I'm just trying for it how to work with ^^ but thanks for tip sir! Your snippet has given me so much ideas that will help me in the future! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `printf` to calculate the sum of the grades. You can use your loop to calculate the `sum` like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  sum = sum + grades[i];
}
```

`printf` is a library function that sends formatted output to the standard output (your screen).

Comment: Ohh! Thanks for that tips and idea sir! Appreciate it a lot! Now I know where to use printf! ^^

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem.

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i)
{
    sum += grades[i];
    avg = sum / (i+1);
    printf ("After adding lecture %u --> sum: %.1f + average: %.1f\n", i+1,sum , avg);
}
```

Comment: If you want answer already answered question, check your answer is different with already given answer. If similar answer is already available, avoid repeating similar answer.

Comment: When answering you should also explain _why_ that would be the correct way to do it and not just provide code to copy & paste, because that leads to [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) :)